# Laravel Model observer in two different servers

Tags: php, laravel, model, observer-pattern, laravel-5.1

I have a question about model observers in laravel. Assume that we have 2 servers(let us call web1 and web2) behind loadbalancer and they both use the same database. User sends a message from browser on "web1", it simply change the value in DB, and the related model observer fires a Google cloud message to a device.

Then device returns a response to "web2", this will also change the value in DB. And we assume that model observer in "web1" will handle the update event even if the value in DB updated from "web2".

And one more question, will they both handle the update event of model? This is not good for us, because 2 same GCM commands will be fired in this case.Is it right, i am confused, could you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: Model events are handled on the server where they are triggered. They happen right away. During the same request.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So in our case, the device response will be handled on web2, but the user session is on web1, and we want to notify user about the operation result that will handled on web2's model observer. How can we make it work? @lukasgeiter

Comment: Not just with model events no. Maybe web2 could notify web1 somehow? or you set a flag in the db and web1 periodically checks for that?